# C++ data for SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, bigdata, svm

I'll use openCV's (C++) SVM(Support Vector Machines) for classification. But have a problem:

Feature vectors are so big (each has 1890000 elements) and I have more than 10000 feature vectors to train SVM. How can I  manipulate feature vectors or use them without experience memory problems?

Comment: I suggest you to use a feature reduction algorithm like PCA.

Comment: 1. Get a fancier computer...looks like you need one with 256 gig of ram. 2. Manupulate them only one at a time or in chunks (the problem is the 10000 multiplier, 1890000 double elements is only 14 megabytes), if possible leave the rest on the harddrive.

Comment: [Dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) is your friend.

Comment: Like what herohuyongtao and gokhans said, dimensionality reduction using PCA, or just remove redundant part of the features vector should help. Right now your SVM training will lots of time, and remember that prediction of SVM is of O( support vectors * size of feature vectors ), so your SVM prediction will be very slow too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such high dimensions and with that many training samples you will require a lot of memory to use any popular implementation of SVM. If I were to face this problem then I would consider at least one of these options:

- Reduce the dimension of each vector, there are plenty of algorithms to do this but PCA is a good start.
- Get computing time in some host with a lot of memory (maybe one of amazon ec2 instances would be suffice)
- Test with a linear online approximation of SVM. In high dimensions, it is very likely that you can separate the classes [linearly](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220550389_On_linear_separability_of_data_sets_in_feature_space) and there are SVM [online approximations](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/PegasosMPB.pdf) that you could use and then load to memory just one sample at a time in which case you don't need as much memory (I would consider pegasos-svm for this).